# Problems with Unity3D Horizontal Slider

Tags: slider, unity-game-engine

I'm quite new to programming/Unity and trying to figure out how to use the OnGUI horizontal slider.
I've got three sliders range 0-100 and want a value named pointsLeft to increase/decrease when the user moves the sliders. Also the total value of the three sliders can't be over 100. I would really appreciate it if someone could help a newbie! See code for more details.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Slider : MonoBehaviour {

public float sliderA = 0.0f;
public float sliderB = 0.0f;
public float sliderC = 0.0f;

public float startingPoints = 100f;
public float pointsLeft;

void Start() {

pointsLeft = startingPoints;

}

void OnGUI () {

GUI.Label(new Rect(250, 10, 100, 25), "Points Left: " + pointsLeft.ToString());

GUI.Label (new Rect (25, 25, 100, 30), "Strength: " + sliderA.ToString());
sliderA = GUI.HorizontalSlider (new Rect (25, 50, 500, 30), (int)sliderA, 0.0f, 100.0f);

GUI.Label (new Rect (25, 75, 100, 30), "Agility: " + sliderB.ToString());
sliderB = GUI.HorizontalSlider (new Rect (25, 100, 500, 30), (int)sliderB, 0.0f, 100.0f);

GUI.Label (new Rect (25, 125, 100, 30), "Intelligence: " + sliderC.ToString());
sliderC = GUI.HorizontalSlider (new Rect (25, 150, 500, 30), (int)sliderC, 0.0f, 100.0f);

/*if(sliderA < pointsLeft) {
pointsLeft = (int)pointsLeft - sliderA; //this is not doing the magic

}

*/
//decrease pointsLeft when the slider increases or increase pointsLeft if slider decreases

//store the value from each slider when all points are spent and the user pressess a button

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Don't update the slider value until you are sure the slider move is valid.

Below, this code stores the new slider values in temp variables, and if the value is below the points allowed then it allows the change:

```
public float pointsMax = 100.0f;
public float sliderMax = 100.0f;
public float pointsLeft;

void OnGUI () {

  // allow sliders to update based on user interaction
  float newSliderA = GUI.HorizontalSlider(... (int)sliderA, 0.0f, sliderMax);
  float newSliderB = GUI.HorizontalSlider(... (int)sliderB, 0.0f, sliderMax);
  float newSliderC = GUI.HorizontalSlider(... (int)sliderC, 0.0f, sliderMax);

  // only change the sliders if we have points left
  if ((newSliderA + newSliderB + newSliderC) < pointsMax) {

    // Update the current values for the sliders to use next time
    sliderA = newSliderA;
    sliderB = newSliderB;
    sliderC = newSliderC;
  }

  // record the new points count
  pointsLeft = pointsMax - (sliderA + sliderB + sliderC);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problems! Had to typecast the floats by using (int)Mathf.Round(newSliderA) because I couldn't get the pointsLeft down to zero when moving more than one slider